# T-SQL: CASE statement in WHERE?

Tags: sql, t-sql, case, where-clause

I have the following WHERE clause in my SQL query currently:

```
WHERE c.Town LIKE '%' + @Town + '%'
```

What I want do is make the first '%' optional - so if the user has selected to just filter by records that just start with the given text, the WHERE would be

```
WHERE c.Town LIKE @Town + '%'
```

I assumed the simplest way to do this would be CASE statements, but I'm having no joy as it seems the syntax is incorrect. Can I get any pointers? Here's the CASE statement I was trying:

```
WHERE c.Town LIKE (CASE WHEN @FilterOptions = 1 THEN '%' ELSE '') + @Town + '%'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed the END:

```
WHERE c.Town LIKE (CASE WHEN @FilterOptions = 1 THEN '%' ELSE '' END) + @Town + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

A `CASE` must end with an `END`. Try

```
WHERE c.Town LIKE (CASE WHEN @FilterOptions = 1 THEN '%' ELSE '' END) + @Town + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Case should have    end.

I think the below statement can help you.

```
WHERE c.Town LIKE (CASE WHEN @FilterOptions = 1 THEN '%' ELSE '' END) + @Town + '%
```